# Pygame subsurface from host to clients

Tags: sockets, udp, pygame

I have a simple UDP server that I'm going to use to make a game you can play on your LAN. Here is how I want my game to run. I have, let's say, 5 players. All players have a x and y position. These to values are given the the host. On the host machine it assembles all these x and y positions into an array. It then blits these players onto a pygame subsurface. I want to then give the clients the updated map so that all they see is the players updated positions. My main concern with all of this is **how do I convert the subsurface into a transferable data type** so the client can receive the encoded data and decode it then print it to their screens.

I don't believe you'll need any code because my question is not specifically aimed at my code but if you do let me know. The only problem with supplying you the code is only bits of it are working as of now and the little that is won't help you much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why try to have the host send surfaces as opposed to simply having it act as a relay and telling all the clients everyone's current positions?

Comment: I thought it be harder to send back a array

Comment: In my opinion, it would be easier and faster to just send an array back and let the client create the surface. Sending just plain text (you could somehow make a format of the array in text) is much faster than sending the many bytes of an image. Especially if you were to be updating very often, the game would not have a high frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone in the future I found the answer to my question. It is simply encoding the image to base64 transferring it then decoding it.

However sending the array formatting and reformatting proved to be more efficents